# Iron router error in meteor 1.0 in production mode

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have upgraded my meteor application from 0.8 to 1.0. It was working fine before upgrade it to 1.0 in Production mode. After upgradation am facing errors in production mode. 
 As I have defined my route in home.js like this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/', 
    controller: 'Controller1'
  });
});

Controller1 = RouteController.extend({  
  layoutTemplate: 'Layout1',      
  onAfterAction: function() {
     setTimeout(function(){  $('#l').focus(); }, 600);
     this.next;
  }  
});
```

In development mode it is working fine but when I run the application in production mode, Its is giving me the error route not found.

Please help me to get out of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by development mode and production mode ? What are the steps neccesary to switch between these modes ?

Comment: in development mode means I run meteor -p 3000, In production mode means meteor -p 3000 --production

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question like @Moshikaro :)

Check out my working Meteorpad.

http://meteorpad.com/pad/fRzpHPYMwRGPirWAD/Routing

**[Edit]**

Your `home.js` should look like this

```
Controller1 = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'Layout1',
  name: 'home',
  onAfterAction: function() {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      $('#l').focus();
    }, 600);
  }
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    controller: 'Controller1'
  });
});
```

Comment: In development mode means I run meteor -p 3000, In production mode means meteor -p 3000 --production

Comment: `--production` simulate production mode. Minify and bundle CSS and JS files. So i think your javascript doesn't work correctly after that.

Could you post your exactly error log? 
Have you tried my Meteorpad solution? :)

Comment: Yes it is not showing any errors in the console, but in the browser it is giving the iron router error like this                           Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}) }
  });
});                                                                       Yes I have checked your solution but I didn't find any answer. Thanks

Comment: check out my edit section in my answer. Paste the code in your current home.js and it should works. 

If not, please paste your COMPLETELY ERROR CODE in a new answer in a `code` formatted block. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

After migrating to meteor 1.0 and thus iron:router 1.0, I had to modify my router.js file. First of all, I only included this.next() in onRun() and onBeforeAction() hooks, you don't need to put it in onAfterAction AFAIK.

Besides, I avoid using Router.map() anymore and I define all routes according to the doc: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router

So try to modify your code like this:

```
Router.route('home', function () {
  this.render('home');
}, {
  layoutTemplate: 'Layout1',
  path: '/',
  onAfterAction: function(){
    setTimeout(function(){  $('#l').focus(); }, 600);
  }
});
```

Cheers,